# Input field inside a radio button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make the input field onclick of a radio button work and it seems like not working.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6qoe89j2/8/

```js
$("#ddlMth").hide();
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "delivery-yes") {
    $("#ddlMth").show();
  } else {
    $("#ddlMth").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radioFrequency" onclick="myMth()" id="radioFrequency-0" value="delivery-yes" /> Yes.
<input type="radio" name="radioFrequency" id="radioFrequency-0" /> No.
<div class="controls">
  <label id="ddlMth" name="ddlMth" class="car-list-step-label" for="country">Test</label>
  <input id="ddlMth" name="ddlMth" type="text" placeholder="e.g £50" class="form-control car-list-input">
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at your browser's developer console.  There's an error message when that page loads.  And another one when you click on your radio buttons.

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made you - you do not have a function myMth  (and do not need one since you use on("change")
 - another big issue is duplicate ID - another is the label has for="country"  which does not exist

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [mcve] to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure they even had jquery loaded

Comment: @AndrewBone certainly not in the fiddle

Comment: `$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  $(".controls").toggle(this.value == "delivery-yes") });`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/snpy47ga/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have same Id for multiple elements. I have changed the Id of label and Input.

**You don't need jQuery, you can do it with CSS.**

See below Snippet :

```css
.controls{
  display:none;
}

input[value="delivery-yes"]:checked ~ .controls {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioFrequency" id="radioFrequency-0" value="delivery-yes" /> Yes.
<input type="radio" name="radioFrequency" id="radioFrequency-0" /> No.
<div class="controls">
  <label id="ddlMthLabel" for="ddlMth" class="ddlMth car-list-step-label">Test</label>
  <input id="ddlMthInput" name="ddlMth" type="text" placeholder="e.g £50" class="ddlMth form-control car-list-input">
</div>
```

Comment: `$("input[type='radio']").change(function() { $(".controls").toggle(this.value == "delivery-yes") });`

Comment: Labels do not have names

Comment: Makes sense.. Thanks for suggestions.. I have removed jQuery and getting the result using CSS.

Comment: Very cute. What is the browser coverage of that css

Answer (score 0):

You set 2 elements with the same `id="ddlMth"`. `id` must be unique. Jquery selects only the first one then hide it. If you want to hide the label and the input, you should hide the container of them:

```js
$("#ddlMth").hide();
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "delivery-yes") {
    $("#ddlMth").show();
  } else {
    $("#ddlMth").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="radioFrequency" id="radioFrequency-0" value="delivery-yes" /> Yes.</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radioFrequency" id="radioFrequency-0" /> No.</label>
<div class="controls" id="ddlMth">
  <label name="ddlMth" class="car-list-step-label" for="country">Test</label>
  <input name="ddlMth" type="text" placeholder="e.g £50" class="form-control car-list-input">
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: but also please note not to answer poor questions that can be solved in a comment and closed

Comment: Also labels do not have names

Comment: `$("input[type='radio']").change(function() { $(".controls").toggle(this.value == "delivery-yes") });`